# MonthCanledar в Windows Forms

Tags: c#

Как можно при нажатии `button` открыть  `MonthCanledar` в Windows Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    monthCalendar1.Show();
}
```

Пробовали?

Что бы изначально не было видно:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    monthCalendar1.Hide();
}
```

Comment: в этом случае должен поставить `monthCalendar` на форму а мне нужно что на форме не было водно календаря до нажатии кнопки

Comment: @VardanVardanyan, обновил ответ.